# How to avoid exceeding normal page limits after revision?

Tags: publications, journals

I wrote a manuscript that was the maximum length (without any page charges) and sent it to the IEEE Journal of Biomedical and Health Informatics. Now the revisions have come. I am in the process of revising it, but I see that after revision there may be an addition of 1 or 2 pages more. Now for these 1 or pages I have to pay approximately $250 which I don't have. How do I avoid this over-length after incorporating all the revisions?

Comment: Are you paying the fee from your own pocket, or charge it to your institution?

Comment: I have marked as duplicate even though the linked question is about "before submitted" where this is about "after revision" because I believe that the answers apply equally well to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I avoid this over-length after incorporating all the revisions?

There are a few tricks that authors typically use to reduce a manuscript's length (especially for conference papers with hard page limitations), but none would be sufficient to shorten a paper by 1-2 pages, and some of them might be nulled by the copy-editor. Moreover, the changes would be so substantial that the reviewers might require a second round of major revision.

Therefore, if you really can't afford those fees because, e.g., you don't have departmental funds, my suggestion is to ask the publisher if they can waive your overlength fees.